# How to insert value/key from a dict in a list in postgres

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql-9.4

im creating a db and want to insert links from a value/key dictionary in a list, looks loke this:

```
"images": [{
        "link": "https://images-url.com/images/I/61lYKVLbPZL0._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
        "variant": "MAIN"
    }, {
        "link": "https://images-url.com/images/I/7165NDvwSKL0._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
        "variant": "PT01"
    }]
```

the insert part is this one:

```
IMAGES = data['product']['images']

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

i want to insert links of the images

Comment: Isn't it used with "=" insted of ":"? Let me know if I am wrong and I will delete my comment. I would try using "images" = [{ etc.

Comment: Im using python3 psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

i solve in this way:
   data =

```
{
    "product": {
        "images": [{
            "link": "https://images-url.com/images/I/61lYKVLbPZL0._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
            "variant": "MAIN"
        }, {
            "link": "https://images-url.com/images/I/7165NDvwSKL0._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
            "variant": "PT01"
        }]
    }
}

images_list = []
images_t = data['product']['images']
for i in images_t:
  images_list.append(i.get('link'))
IMAGES = images_list
```